# Dot product for lists

Tags: list-manipulation, dot, inner

Suppose we want to get the dot product for the following lists `aa` and `bb`, whose elements (`a`, `b`, etc.) are also lists. We can get the symbolic expression of `aa.bb` first, and then assign numerical values of the elements in `aa` and `bb`.

```
aa = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
bb = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}};
cc = aa.bb;
(* -> {{{a^2 + a b, a b + b^2}, {a c + b c, a d + b d}}, {{a c + a d, b c + b d}, {c^2 + c d, c d + d^2}}} *)
a = b = c = d = {1, 2, 3}
cc
(* -> {{{{2, 8, 18}, {2, 8, 18}}, {{2, 8, 18}, {2, 8, 18}}}, {{{2, 8, 18}, {2, 8, 18}}, {{2, 8, 18}, {2, 8, 18}}}} *)
```

However, if we do not want to get the symbolic expression for `aa.bb` (because it is too long in some situations), and only use numerical calculations, we cannot directly use `Dot` in the same way as follows. Is there a simple way to fix this?

```
aa = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
bb = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}};
a = b = c = d = {1, 2, 3};
cc = aa.bb
(* -> Dot::dotsh: Tensors {{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}},{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}} and {{{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}},{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}},{{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}},{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}}} have incompatible shapes. >> *)
```

Comment: Have you seen `Inner[]`?

Comment: `Dot` works as you desire only when the dimensions are compatible; for example, with `a=b=c=d={1,2}`.

Comment: Related: [Easy way to perform multiplication of two 2x2 matrices, that contain list elements?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65409/14303), but in a sense answer there uses kind of intermediate symbolic representation, so it might not be a best answer to this question.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Can this be done with inner? I thought so too, but cant make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not pretty but there is always this:

```
 Table[Sum[aa[[i, j]] bb[[j, k, l ]],{j,2}],{i,2},{k,2},{l,2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the entire symbolic product is too large perhaps it is sufficient to work in chunks:

```
aa = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
bb = {aa, aa};

rule = a | b | c | d -> {1, 2, 3};
Table[x.y /. rule, {x, aa}, {y, bb\[Transpose]}]
```

> ```
> {{{{2, 8, 18}, {2, 8, 18}}, {{2, 8, 18}, {2, 8, 18}}},
>  {{{2, 8, 18}, {2, 8, 18}}, {{2, 8, 18}, {2, 8, 18}}}}
> ```